# How to do Maven Clean and maven update project in Intellij idea

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am shifted from eclipse to intellij idea to work with my Spring boot project. there i found only maven clean option, but I am unable to find out how to do maven update. instead there it has maven build option, the build option created .class files. But i need to update only my dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

To update the dependency it is enough to update its version in pom.xml and invoke **Reload All Maven Projects** action in Maven tool window. If dependency is not updated there is some problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

step by step :
[image: click here]

[image: click here]

[image: code]

> and your enter : mvn clean update

Comment: maven clean update goal is not there bro

Comment: You just need to type it and press the Enter button

Comment: ha entered like that only bro shows build fails

Answer (score 0):

inside in IntelliJ, instead of Using maven update, we are using the maven install. so that it will install all the dependencies and update the project.
[image: CHeck the image]